# How to set locale to tika server?

Tags: apache-tika, tika-server

In tika mvn dependency there is ability to set default locale

Example:

```
        ParseContext context = new ParseContext();
        context.set(Locale.class, Locale.forLanguageTag("fra"));
```

What header or parameter in config should i use for tika server in docker?

Comment: Set an environment variable like you would for a local linux machine?

Comment: @Gagravarr ok, i`ll try